# MySQL Full Text Search not working properly. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, myisam

**OBS:** I'm new to Full Text Searches and MyIsam engine, so assue I know basically nothing about it.

Here's my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE NotebookIndex (
    indexAutomatico TEXT,
    indexHumano TEXT,
    notebook BIGINT UNSIGNED
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE=MYISAM;
ALTER TABLE NotebookIndex ADD FULLTEXT(indexAutomatico, indexHumano);
```

And here's my database right now:

[image]

When I query:

```
SELECT notebook FROM NotebookIndex WHERE MATCH(indexHumano, indexAutomatico) AGAINST ('intel')
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

If you look closely to the print screen, you will be able to see that `'intel'` does exists in some of the lines.

Although, if I change `'intel'` to `'sony'` i get some results. I tried some other (existent) words and it doesn't work either. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the word is present in more then 50% of the rows, it will be ignored in [natural full text searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). If you need results spanning more then 50% of your table, go for [BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: I'll test it in a few minutes and give you feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @Weikkrn, i didn't understand about 50%, could you explain it briefly?